# Why does area under curve not change from 0.5?

Tags: r, logistic, ridge-regression, auc, glmnet

I have performed a ridge logistic regression with `glmnet` and now I look at the performance metric `AUC`. The script is:

```
library(readr)
library(caret)
library(tidyverse)
library(glmnet)
library(ROCR)
library(pROC)
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(4, cores = 4)

data <- read_csv("data.csv")

df <- data %>% select(V1, V2, V3, V_dependent, V5, V6, V7, V8)
training.samples <- df$V_dependent %>% createDataPartition(p = 0.8, list = FALSE)
train <- df[training.samples, ]
test <- df[-training.samples, ]
x.train <- data.frame(train[, names(train) != "V_dependent"])
x.train <- data.matrix(x.train)
y.train <- train$V_dependent
x.test <- data.frame(test[, names(test) != "V_dependent"])
x.test <- data.matrix(x.test)
y.test <- test$V_dependent
foldid <- sample(rep(seq(10), length.out = nrow(train)))

#CROSS-VALIDATION LOG.REGRESSION
list.of.fits <- cv.glmnet(x.train, y.train, type.measure = "dev", alpha = 0, family = "binomial", nfolds = 10, foldid = foldid, parallel = TRUE, standardized = TRUE)

#ROC CURVE
predicted_obs <- predict(list.of.fits, s = list.of.fits$lambda.1se, newx = x.test, type = 'response')
pred_obs <- prediction(predicted, y.test)
perf_obs <- performance(pred, "tpr", "fpr")
plot(perf_obs, color = "black")
plot(perf_exp, color = "red")
abline(a = 0, b = 1, lty = 2, col = "red")

auc_ROCR <- performance(pred, measure = "auc")
auc_ROCR <- auc_ROCR@y.values[[1]]
auc_ROCR
ci.auc(y.test, as.vector(predicted), method = 'b')
```

I get an `AUC` of `0.5` and between `0.5 - 0.5` with bootstrapping. The ROC-curve is equal to the 1:1 line, but would we not expect some noise around the 1:1 line rather than completely equal to it (Figure below)?

[image: untitled]

1. Why do we not see 'noise' around the 1:1 line as the expectation (Figure)?
2. How can we explain this flat, rigid value of 0.5 for the AUC?

EDIT: Here are the regression coefficients

```
(Intercept)    -1.700559e+01
V1              3.703064e-04
V2             -4.168570e-02
V3              3.576656e-03
V4             -2.812728e-06
V5              5.974140e-03
V6              1.427104e-02
V7              3.763967e-04
V8              2.979648e-02
```

Comment: Please double-check that the code you show is what was used to generate the plot. The code (5th line from bottom) specifies a red color for `abline`, a straight line, yet on the plot the red line is wiggly and seems to correspond to the ROC curve.

Comment: Also look at the ridge regression coefficients.  They must be pretty small.  And determine the apparently optimum amount of shrinkage.  How many events and non-events do you have?  You need a certain number of events to be able to reliably estimate the amount of shrinkage needed.

Comment: @EdM, the `black` line is the observed AUC and that follows the 1:1 line which is the red `abline`. They may be hard to see in the plot - take a closer look. The wiggly red line is just my expectation for the AUC, and therefore I cannot understand why the observed AUC follows a 1:1 line so close and does not look like the wiggly red line. Makes sense?

Comment: @FrankHarrell, the regression coefficients are relatively small indeed. My events vs. non-events are very unbalanced: 1:1000, which sums up to 1500 : 1,500,000 for the whole dataset. I will immediately add the coefficients to the question. Any explanation why the AUC equals the 1:1 line?

Comment: If you do not have a programming error, the $c$-index (concordance probability; AUROC) will be 0.5 if the shrinkage is severe as in that case $X\hat{\beta}$ is relatively constant.  Note that the ROC curve is irrelevant unless you have a retrospective case-control study.  You may do better with unsupervised learning (sparse principal components, variable clustering followed by regular PCs for each variable cluster, etc.).  I cover these in [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rms).  Penalized regression is a diffused method, i.e., it spreads out the penalization.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @FrankHarrell. Does my `test data` (consisting of 20 % 'unused' data) serve as the retrospective case-control study you mention?

Comment: No, retrospective case-control data would arise had you sampled 3000 observations with Y=0 and 3000 observations with Y=1.  The points on ROC curves are irrelevant when you did not condition on Y in the beginning.  This is one of the most misunderstood things in statistics.  See [here](https://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage).

Comment: Should I condition on Y? Are you indicating that I have done something wrong statistically?
By the way, I have looked at the `brier score` too, however, that does not really say much. It does not change drastically in any case. It stays relatively low ~0.005